# AWS SDK Lex PostText Error: TruncatingBigNumber can not be converted to an String

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-lex

I've been using AWS SDK (PHP) LexRuntimeService for a while and this is a sudden error that occurs for seemingly random cases.

PostText Args are set like this, depending on user input and data:

```
(
[botAlias] => xxxxx
[botName] => xxxxxxx
[inputText] => book a ride
[userId] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[requestAttributes] => Array
    (
        [userID] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        [userInput] => book a ride
        [passenger_first_name] => xxxxxxxx
        [passenger_last_name] => xxxxxx
        [passenger_email] => xxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com
        [channel] => facebook
        [chatbot_session_id] => xx
    )
)
```

These PostText Args should be what determines this error, but I cannot find any difference between working Args and erroring Args. When the SDK errors, this is what I get:

> Aws\LexRuntimeService\Exception\LexRuntimeServiceException:
>
> Error executing \"PostText\" on \"https://runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bot/xxxxxxx/alias/xxxxxx/user/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/text\";
>
> AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https:\/\/runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/bot\/xxxxx\/alias\/xxxxx\/user\/xxxxxxxxxxxx\/text`
>
> resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{\"Message\":\"class com.amazon.coral.value.json.numbers.TruncatingBigNumber can not be converted to an String\"}\n SerializationException (client): - {\"Message\":\"class com.amazon.coral.value.json.numbers.TruncatingBigNumber can not be converted to an String\"} in /var/www/html/yt074/thirdparty/aws/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 193</i></th></tr>\n

I've tried setting each of the Args to strings like this:

```
$requestAttributes["userID"] = (string) $userData['userID'];
```

But the error still occurs. Any suggestions/explanations for what might cause this error?